# Reading Upper and Lower Bytes from Buffer with Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, byte, buffer

I'm screwing around and building a zip file reader in Node JS. I've encountered a point in the zip spec where I'm not quite sure how to proceed.

I have a buffer that has two bytes containing data for `version made by`. There is an upper byte which tells which system the zip file was made by and there is a lower byte which tells which version of the zip spec was used to create the file.

How do I read the upper byte and lower byte from the buffer? Right now my code is just doing:

```
var madeBy = buffer.readUInt16LE(4); // 4 is the offset of `version made by`
```

This unsigned integer ends up being a a number which I think is useless.

Also, I don't know what upper/lower byte means, so if you could explain that to me that would also be helpful. :)

---

For reference, here's a link to the documentation for Node JS buffers and also what the zip spec says:

https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html

```
4.4.2 version made by (2 bytes)

4.4.2.1 The upper byte indicates the compatibility of the file
attribute information.  If the external file attributes 
are compatible with MS-DOS and can be read by PKZIP for 
DOS version 2.04g then this value will be zero.  If these 
attributes are not compatible, then this value will 
identify the host system on which the attributes are 
compatible.  Software can use this information to determine
the line record format for text files etc.  

4.4.2.2 The current mappings are:

 0 - MS-DOS and OS/2 (FAT / VFAT / FAT32 file systems)
 1 - Amiga                     2 - OpenVMS
 3 - UNIX                      4 - VM/CMS
 5 - Atari ST                  6 - OS/2 H.P.F.S.
 7 - Macintosh                 8 - Z-System
 9 - CP/M                     10 - Windows NTFS
11 - MVS (OS/390 - Z/OS)      12 - VSE
13 - Acorn Risc               14 - VFAT
15 - alternate MVS            16 - BeOS
17 - Tandem                   18 - OS/400
19 - OS X (Darwin)            20 thru 255 - unused

4.4.2.3 The lower byte indicates the ZIP specification version 
(the version of this document) supported by the software 
used to encode the file.  The value/10 indicates the major 
version number, and the value mod 10 is the minor version 
number.
```

Comment: Because you used the C++ tag, this shows up in my feed.  I don't see how this question relates to C++.

Answer (score 0):

For [zip file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)#File_headers) types, file header description is like this:

```
A.  Local file header:

local file header signature     4 bytes  
version needed to extract       2 bytes
general purpose bit flag        2 bytes
compression method              2 bytes
last mod file time              2 bytes
last mod file date              2 bytes
crc-32                          4 bytes
compressed size                 4 bytes
uncompressed size               4 bytes
filename length                 2 bytes
extra field length              2 bytes
```

Since the values are stored as little-endian, you have to read them in reverse order:

```
var buffer = fs.readFileSync('/input.zip'),
 versionHeader = buffer.slice(4,6) //taking 5th & 6th byte according to spec.
 host = versionHeader [1] 
 majorVersion = versionHeader[0]/10
 minorVersion = versionHeader[0]%10
```

for zip files, with first 6 bytes like this:

```
50 4b 03 04 14 00
```

prints `host=0` e.g. MS-DOS and `version=2.0` e.g. major version 2 and minor version 0.

---

To explain upper and lower bytes:

```
var versionHeader = buffer.readUInt16LE(4) // outputs 20
```

Since it's 16bit, decimal 20 can written as `0x0014` in Hex. Here upper byte is `0x00`(=0 in decimal) and Lower byte is `0x14`(=20 in decimal).